# Jenkins groovy pipeline - Need stdout of command from executing jar file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins v:1.647 and the Pipeline plugin v: 1.14. My pipeline job pulls a groovy script which runs my orchestration. My issue is I have a executable jar that will perform some Scalr API operations and return a new servers hostname, passed in standard out. I have a working snippet that works outside of Jenkins.

```
def serverHostName = "java -jar scalr-api.jar testing654 n1-standard-8".execute().text
```

This code works fine outside of Jenkins but my issue is when running my pipeline I receive the ever annoying RejectedAccessException.But unlike the other script security exceptions there is not option for me to approve the method in question.

Im looking any solution that can get past the script security and allow me to run that jar and get the standard out to use later in my script

Thanks

Jenkins error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method java.lang.UNIXProcess getText
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:74)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:15)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:97)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:74)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:106)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:277)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:77)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:186)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a shell command from the pipeline script using `sh` step. The trick is to redirect the executed command's output to a file and then read it with `readFile` in the next step.

This should do what you want on linux slave:

```
sh "java -jar scalr-api.jar testing654 n1-standard-8 > scalr.out"
def out = readFile 'scalr.out'
```

On windows slave:

```
bat "java -jar scalr-api.jar testing654 n1-standard-8 > scalr.out"
def out = readFile 'scalr.out'
```

Comment: I came to this same solution and it worked well for me. Ultimately I changed strategy and im having pipeline execute a single script which holds the bulk of my logic. I needed to do this because the sandbox securities is a mess to work with, and Im forced to use sandbox when pulling from SCM.

Answer (score 10):

As of version 2.4 of *[Pipeline: Nodes and Processes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Nodes+and+Processes+Plugin#PipelineNodesandProcessesPlugin-2.4%28Jul28%2C2016%29)* it suffices to use:

```
def out = sh script: 'java -jar scalr-api.jar testing654 n1-standard-8', returnStdout: true
```