# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin: execute shell and parse output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the Jenkins Pipeline plugin to execute an iOS Checkout-Build-Test-Deploy pipeline.

One step involves checking whether an iDevice is actually connected (otherwise the rest of the steps will not be executed).

I want to execute a shell command `idevice_id -l` (from [libimobiledevice](http://libimobiledevice.org)) which will print out the device ID of the connected device, or fail if nothing connected.

So the steps as I envision them, would be:

- Execute command `sh "/usr/local/bin/idevice_id -l"`
- parse the output somehow
- fail if this command does not return anything.

I have read most of the official docs, but drew a blank. How do I parse the output of the `sh` step?
If I am approaching this in the wrong way, any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046361/702954), as of version 2.4 of *[Pipeline: Nodes and Processes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Nodes+and+Processes+Plugin#PipelineNodesandProcessesPlugin-2.4%28Jul28%2C2016%29)* you can use:

```java
def out = sh script: '/usr/local/bin/idevice_id -l', returnStdout: true
```

Comment: `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 43: Expected a step @ line 43, column 17.
                   def out = sh script: './script.sh', returnStdout: true
                   ^

1 error`

Answer (score 4):

The official method is to redirect the output into a file and read the file

If the output file is empty, you can fail the job with the pipeline script command `error "no device connected"`

[Example on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/gitcommit/gitcommit.groovy)

Comment: fantastic! This works for me fine.  `sh('/usr/local/bin/idevice_id -l > DEVICE_ID'); deviceId=readFile('GIT_COMMIT')`

Comment: This is not the "official" method/workaround anymore, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39102404/702954) for updated method.