# Capture and send output from sh method in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that is running a shell command and I want to send the output of that `sh` method as the `message:` of the `slackSend` method.

I have the following so far, but the message to the slack channel is empty. I'm not certain how to capture the output in a way that I can reference it in the message section:

```
node {

        checkout scm

        stage 'run shell command'

        def shell_command =  sh "ls -l"
        def shell_output = apply_cluster

        stage 'notify slack-notification'
        slackSend channel: '#slack-notifications', color: 'good', message:     shell_output, teamDomain: 'company', token: env.SLACK_TOKEN
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Pipeline Plugin: execute shell and parse output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304131/jenkins-pipeline-plugin-execute-shell-and-parse-output)

Answer (score 3):

After a little more research, I discovered a couple of things I did not initially understand: The first is that even with defining a function in a Jenkinsfile, if it's a DSL method like `sh`, it will still get executed, so the second function I defined isn't necessary. Second, if you want to return stdout, you have to specify that as part of the command. The new code looks like this:

```
node {

        checkout scm

        stage 'run shell command'

        def shell_command =  sh script: "ls -l", returnStdout: true

        stage 'notify slack-notification'
        slackSend channel: '#slack-notifications', color: 'good', message: shell_command, teamDomain: 'company', token: env.SLACK_TOKEN
}
```