# Getting git tags that doesn't contain character

Tags: git, shell, glob

I'm trying to create a pattern to use with git ls-remote (`git ls-remote -t origin "<mypattern>"`) to get the tags that do not end with `-<number>`. It needs to be with ls-remote because I'm trying to use it in a Jenkins pipeline that uses this command internally.

For example with following tags:

```
refs/tags/foo-bar-1.0.0
refs/tags/foo-bar-1.0.1-1
refs/tags/foo-bar-1.0.1-2
refs/tags/foo-bar-1.0.1
refs/tags/foo-bar-1.0.2
```

I would like to exclude the ones ending with `-1` and `-2`.

I could to it easily with regex: `foo-bar-\d+(.\d+){2}$`, but the command doesn't accept regex.

I tried the patterns `*foo-bar-*[!-]*"` and `*foo-bar-*.*.*[!-]*` and they didn't work, they ended up getting all tags.

Am I missing something about the `!` operator?

Comment: Can you pipe the output of `git ls-remote` into grep and use your regex?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon unfortunately I can't, since I'm using Git Parameter Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) to create a parameter for the job to select which tag it should build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell globs are not powerful enough to do this.  You need real regular expressions, or a programming language, to achieve what you want.  You can easily invoke `git ls-remote | grep` from a shell: see [Jenkins Pipeline Plugin: execute shell and parse output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36304131/1256452).