# Jenkins Pipeline - Reading previous stage log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider a Jenkins Pipeline with two stages, **Stage A** then **Stage B**.

In Stage B, is it possible to parse the logs of Stage A for some particular text?

Comment: I depends what kind of logs you need. E.g. if you want parse gradle output probably you can redirect standard output to file and next read file and parse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's been an update since July 28th !

As mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046361/702954), as of version 2.4 of *[Pipeline: Nodes and Processes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Nodes+and+Processes+Plugin#PipelineNodesandProcessesPlugin-2.4%28Jul28%2C2016%29)* you can use:

```java
def out = sh script: 'command', returnStdout: true
```

At least it's much more simple and clean than outputting to a file and reading the file afterwards.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can help me to parse a previous "step", because I used the **copyArtifact** plugin which needs a "step" (so in my case it's not a command, so I can't use "sh script"), I created a question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601108/jenkins-copy-artifact-parse-copied-build-id

Answer (score 6):

Use `tee` to split the output to both stdout and file. Next parse the file for your text.

```
STAGE_A_LOG_FILE = 'stage_a.log'

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage A') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // tee log into file
                    tee(STAGE_A_LOG_FILE) {
                        echo 'print some Stage_A log content ...'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Stage B') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // search log file for 'Stage_A'
                    regex = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('some (Stage_A) log')
                    matcher = regex.matcher(readFile(STAGE_A_LOG_FILE))
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        echo "found: ${matcher.group(1)}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pipeline output:

```
print some Stage_A log content ...
found: Stage_A
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Unfortunately `tee` has [some issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54346).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for the first occurrance of a pattern, you can also use `manager.logContains(regexp)` or `manager.getLogMatcher(regexp)`. See my other answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39873765/4527766